# Checking temperature conditions

Tags: java

How could I set appropriate temperature within these three conditions at least at 98°C, 99°C, 1°C & 2°C etc?

```
package boiling.freezing;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BoilingFreezing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Give the temperature : ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int temp = sc.nextInt();
        if (temp >= 100){
            System.out.println("The water is boiling!");
        }
        else if (temp <= 0){
            System.out.println("The water is freezing!");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The water is at normal_state!");
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you please elobrate more what you want to achive here?

Comment: I wanna create such a program in which appropriate temperature can be checked, even for 98°C, 99°C, 1°C & 2°C etc

Comment: The above of my program is not doing soo...
Its showing normal state at 98°C and 99°C instead of that I want it to show : "near to boil!"

Comment: @ayeshariaz_ash see my answer.

Comment: please edit the question to explain what you want to do and what is your problem @ayeshariaz_ash

Comment: I wanna create such a program in which appropriate temperature can be checked, even for 98°C, 99°C, 1°C & 2°C etc
The above of my program is not doing so... 
Its showing normal state at 98°C and 99°C instead of that I want it to show : "near to boil!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to offer you a *pattern*, not a simple `if-elseif-else` block.

You might want to have an interface `Temperature`

```
interface Temperature {
   /** Returns true if the temperature matches the criteria. */
   boolean within(final int temperature);

   /** Returns an appropriate, descriptive, message. */
   String message();
}
```

You can then implement this interface to meet your multiple criteria

```
class BoilingTemperature implements Temperature {
   public boolean within(final int temperature) {
      return temperature > 99;
   }

   public String message() {
      return "Water boiling";
   }
}

class FreezingTemperature implements Temperature {
   public boolean within(final int temperature) {
      return temperature < 1; // Should be 3 degree! But anyway.
   }

   public String message() {
      return "Water freezing";
   }
}
```

You can use this pattern to write custom temperature handlers

```
class YourCustomTemperature implements Temperature {
   public boolean within(final int temperature) {
      return temperature > 6 && temperature < 40;
   }

   public String message() {
      return "Your custom message";
   }
}
```

You need to maintain a list of those concrete implementations and loop them to check which matches.

```
final List<Temperature> temperatures = new ArrayList<>(6);
temperatures.add(new BoilingTemperature());
temperatures.add(new FreezingTemperature());
temperatures.add(new YourCustomTemperature());
...
```

And then

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Give the temperature : ");
    final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int temp = sc.nextInt();

    for (final Temperature t : temperatures) {
       if (t.within(temp)) {
          System.out.println(t.message());
       } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know much about it but I'm going to try it!

Comment: LppEdd what you think using predicate will be much cleaner way of implementing this? Anyways I up voted your answer.

Comment: @sandeshdahake I'd say having an interface which *describes* the domain you're working on is always better. In this specific case I worded it as Temperature, but other words might be better suited. Predicate is okay, but it's more general. I'd use Predicates while working over Streams, for example, because the operation is contained in a small block of code.

Comment: Predicates can be passed to lambdas not necessarily always stream. I still prefer using functional interface over writing my own

Comment: @sandeshdahake the Temperature interface might be considered a *functional* interface. Using custom interfaces to model your code is usually better than taking pre-defined, all-around, ones. But if you feel more accustomed to using JDK ones, than do so. It's not an issue at all. The important thing is the code must be clear. That's all ;)

Answer (score 0):

Based on LppEdd's answer if you are using Java 8+ you can make use of java predicate

> java.util.function.Predicate was introduced that behaves as an assignment target in lambda expressions and
>   functional interfaces. The functional method of Predicate is
>   test(Object) .